# Typescript errors when using objects as enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am using a structure like this to make enum-like objects when writing typescript as some simple operations are not supported by typescripts enums, but I am getting some errors which I can't easily solve similar to the following case:

```js
const keys = <const>{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4',
  key5: 'value5',
};
const a: typeof keys[keyof typeof keys] = keys.key1;
if ([ keys.key2, keys.key3 ].includes(a)) { // Argument of type '"value1"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"value2" | "value3"'
  console.log('It is');
} else {
  console.log('It is not');
}
```

Do you know what is the cause of this error?
Also if you have any suggestions how to improve my flow of managing enums it would be great.

Comment: The issue is that `includes()` doesn't allow a wider argument, even though it probably should.  See the linked q/a for more info.  My approach would be to widen the array type to accommodate the input, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9YDVN)